# How to use findAllBy() with pagination?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on a project where I want to search for people based on skills they say they have on their profile. I want to use the `findAllBy();` function but I'm not sure how this works with the Pagination component packaged with CakePHP.

Comment: Instead of using `findAllBy`, use `find` with the needed `condition` clause.  Then use that clause with the paginator.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditions in Paginator, like :

```
public function skills($skill = null){
  $this->Paginator->settings = array(
      'conditions' => array(
          'skill LIKE' => '%'.$skill.'%'
       )
  );
  $people = $this->Paginator->paginate('People');
  $this->set('people', $people);
}
```